# Loading the rest of the page then flushing a loop in its body using PHP

Tags: php, html, ajax, server, flush

I want to load the layout of the page, i.e. header, navigation bar and footer, but implement a long running loop in the body in between the navigation bar and the footer, that flushes what it has done every once in a while. For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <body>
        <header><!--some stuff--></header>
        <nav><!--some stuff--></nav>
        <article>
            <h1>Flushtest</h1>
            <section>
<?php
    for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {
        echo "Test-$i!<br>";
        flush();
        ob_flush();
        sleep(1);
    }
?>
            </section>
        </article>
        <footer><!--some stuff--></footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

If I do this, it loads the header and the navigation bar, then every second a new "Test-*n*" message appears, and when the last test appears, the footer finally appears.
I want the footer to already appear, then load the middle of the page while flushing. Any way to do that?

I tried using AJAX to do it, but either I force it to go very slowly, or it raises a "Too many requests" error. Also, I want the page to still show a 'loading' icon in its tab, and AJAX does not do this.

**EDIT**
Of course, I've struggled with this for days, and the day after asking here I've found my solution: just use `iframe`s.

Comment: Instead of doing a load of individual ajax requests, why not load your page and then make a single ajax request to another PHP file that does whatever it is your loop is doing?

Comment: @BrettGregson Because I can't flush while the PHP file is running if I do that. The AJAX function to put the result of the PHP file into the page doesn't get called until the PHP script is done.

Comment: Ah so you want each item to appear as they complete, not just render the header/footer with a loader. How many ajax requests would it be if done individually?

Comment: @BrettGregson Exactly. It would be around 250 requests. Using some trial and error, I fount that I need to set a 500 millisecond delay between each request to prevent a "too many requests" message. I've now almost found what I'm looking for, though. I'm using an `iframe` that outputs each item as they complete. The only problem now is that the `iframe` does not get enlarged every item. What I need is an event that fires when the contents of the `iframe` change, and 'load' does not seem to do the trick.

Comment: You can try using `postMessage` to communicate between the iframe and the parent (to set the size when the iframe is loaded) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage